# How can I retain a the selection of a DropDownList inside a DataList across a postback?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, viewstate, datalist

I'm a beginner at ASP.NET, but I'm trying to fix a bug in an application written by someone else: a drop-down list's selection is not retained across a postback.

Here are what I believe are the relevant parts of the code:

```
<asp:DataList ... OnItemDataBound="PopulateDropDownList">
    ...
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ... AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DoSomething"/> 
    </FooterTemplate>                               
</asp:DataList>
```

I believe I could store the current selection in the session, a static variable or somewhere else, but this seems more like a work-around then a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague pointed out that the `Page_Load` method was re-binding the `DataList` even if the current request was a post-back. The problem was resolved by changing this to only bind the data to the `DataList` if the request is not a post-back.

This seems to be the root cause of the problem, so I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can set the EnableViewState to "true" - as below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ... EnableViewState="true" ...>
</asp:DropDownList>`
```

But I am not 100% sure if it works the same way inside a DataList, but I am guessing it should.

You can learn more about the view state from [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Make sure you only enable the ViewState for the controls you absolutely need, otherwise you would run into memory issues. From the above source (emphasis mine):

> The EnableViewState property is defined in the System.Web.UI.Control class, so all server controls have this property, including the Page class. **You can therefore indicate that an entire page's view state need not be saved by setting the Page class's EnableViewState to False.** (This can be done either in the code-behind class with Page.EnableViewState = false; or as a @Page-level directive - <%@Page EnableViewState="False" %>.

Comment: The designer indicates that this is `true` by default. I don't have it set to `false`.

Comment: @Sam: For page level, yes, the `EnableViewState` is true by default, but for individual controls you have to set it explicitly. Please see my edit. Let me know if you are still having trouble.

Comment: @Sam: Can you also try setting the EnableViewState for `<asp:DataList` control to true and see if that works?

Comment: (Sorry; I removed my last comment.)

Comment: Explicitly enabling the view state on the `DropDownList` did not work. However, when I also explicitly *disabled* the view state on the page, it *did* work.

Comment: @Sam: So you have the ViewState for Dropdownlist set to true and set the Page to false, right? I guess my answer should have read "You **should** set the page to false". Anyway, glad to see you got it working. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes; that's right. However, disabling view state for the entire page breaks other functionality. (This is probably because I'll have to re-enable it for the specific child controls that need it.) Is there a way to do this without first disabling it for the page?

Comment: @Sam: The reason for disabling the page's view state is so that it will **not** keep the view state for the controls that we don't need to retain after post-backs, thus reducing the overhead (which is critical for pages that have heavy controls). It's always better to keep the view state enabled **only** when needed. As per any other way of doing it, I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 0):

First check Page view state is set to True of False. Including EnableViewState="true" will definitely serve your purpose here, you need not to save the selection in session etc.

Comment: This worked in a very simple test page that I set up, but in the actual page, which is very large, this did not work.

Comment: Nah; it's almost 1000 lines long and it's from a commercial project.

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind, doing the data-binding in the page's `Init` event rather than `Load` event works around the problem. However, a disadvantage of this is some control values are not populated during `Init`.